# Add and remove views

Tags: ember.js

I would like to insert in the DOM a view that displays a form with 2 buttons: + and -;
when you click "+" another identical view is inserted, when you press "-" the current view is removed;

I've tried to create a container view and the function for adding a view is simple:
in the template:

```
{{view Ember.ContainerView elementId="containerView"}}
```

in the childView's template:

```
<button class="form-button" {{action "addProduct"}}>+</button>
```

in the route's controller:

```
 addProduct: function() {
        var container = Ember.View.views['containerView']; 
        var child = container.createChildView(Gmcontrolpanel.InserisciProdottoView);
        container.pushObject(child);

    }
```

But i'm not able to manage the "-" function; because for that i need to get the view that the button i'm clicking belongs to in order to remove it, and i don't know how to do this;
All the childviews can have a controller? Because from the childview's button i can only call actions from the route's controller;

Or there is a better way to get this work?

Comment: where this `-' button placed??...inside added childview or outside??

Comment: Inside the childrenview like the add button. Every child should have his own button for removing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so in that case, have an action in the childview rather controller like this

```
<button class="form-button" {{action "deleteProduct" target="view"}}>-</button>
```

in the views actions handle the deleteProduct like this

```
deleteProduct: function() {
   this.destroy();
}
```

If you want to handle any of the model part then send an event from above method to controller